# Same CSS files are loaded multiple times first in the begining and then at the end?

Tags: php, html, css

I am attaching two images. First images is from the beginning:

[image]

This is second image towards the end of loading process:

[image]

As you can see same files are being loaded three times. First time in the beginning and then at the end. What can cause this issue?

I am using PHP like this:

```
<?php require_once("header.php")?>
All my HTML content
<?php require_once("footer.php")?>
```

But I am including link to CSS files only in header. It only happens with CSS files and not JavaScript files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generated by the [prefixFree plugin](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @davcs86 which tool or browser did you use to get this information?

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check if any of your css-files contains a `@import url("xxx.css");`-statement.

That might be your problem, if css-files imports other css-files, and they import yet again.